# Exporting objects group in gltf format

Tags: three.js, gltf

In Blender i have differents objects that i would group as unique entity. 
What i really care is that after the exportation of the scene in gltf format and importation in my three.js project that group corresponds to a three.js group.
Somebody can help me?

Comment: If you've parented your objects to an empty object in Blender, that should remain true after loading the model in three.js. Try loading the glTF model in https://sandbox.babylonjs.com/, then clicking the "Inspect" button on the bottom right. You can then see the node graph on the left sidebar.